# onClick in React is not working

Tags: reactjs

I know this question has been asked a bunch of times. I've looked at many solutions, and I'm almost positive I have the correct syntax. However, my console.log isn't coming up in the function I expect to execute due to the onClick event. Am I missing something very simple? Thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from './Header';
import AddButton from './AddButton';
import CardContainer from './CardContainer';
import style from '../style/App.css';



class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      cardTitles: ['first', 'second', 'third']
    };
    this.addCard = this.addCard.bind(this);
  }

  addCard(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('ADDED')
    this.state.cardTitles.push('new');
    this.setState({
      cardTitles: this.state.cardTitles
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className={style.appContainer}>
          <Header/>
          <AddButton onClick={this.addCard}/>
          <CardContainer cardTitles={this.state.cardTitles}/>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Here is the server code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();


app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../builds'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));









app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening on port 3000!');
});
```

Here is the AddButton component:

```
import React from 'react';
import style from '../style/AddButton.css';

const AddButton = () => {
  return (
    <div className={style.addButtonContainer}>
        &#43; Add Note
    </div>
  );
};


export default AddButton;
```

Comment: I agree. Any advice on why the console.log isn't appearing?

Comment: Can you post the code for your `AddButton` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are calling the `onClick` function that you are passing as props to the `AddButton` component otherwise it won't be triggered.

You will need to put the following code somewhere in `AddButton`

```
this.props.onClick();
```

So, assuming `AddButton` has an underlying `<button>` element, your render in `AddButton` will look something like this.

```
render() {
  return <button onClick={this.props.onClick}>Add</button>
}
```

Comment: The AddButton is the button itself. I'm not trying to pass it to the AddButton component, I'm just trying to call addCard when AddButton is clicked.

Comment: What you are doing is passing `onClick` as a prop to the `AddButton` component, you then need to use this prop on a DOM element within `AddButton` in order to trigger the event. If you add the following onto the `<div>` in `AddButton` it will work: `onClick={this.props.onClick}`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it working. You should mark my answer as correct so everyone else knows you've fixed your issue.